# Insert text data into image datatype using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I want to insert text into `image` datatype and then want to fetch it. And I am using SQL Server 2000. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***WHY*** on earth do you want to do this? `Image` is for **binary** data - not for text.... large volumes of text should be stored in `TEXT` columns in SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 2):

You can insert data using the normal INSERT statement.  Data can be retrieved by using the normal SELECT statement.  If you are using stored procedures just insert the value of the variable into the table like any other column.